# How can I remove one of the two MATE panels without using the GUI?

Tags: command-line, mate

On a default installation MATE sets up two panels (top and bottom), I'd like to have the top panel removed using `mateconftool-2` or another tool using the command line (Terminal).

I can't find how to do this though (from the Terminal), so I tried deleting the directory in `~/.mateconf/apps/panel/toplevels/` and restarting the panel but it does nothing and so  the panel is still there.

How can I remove one of the panels ***not*** using the **GUI**?

Comment: logout and relogin

Comment: That's the same as restarting the panel, doesn't work.

Comment: Do you tried removing the panel with right click of the mouse?

Comment: @NotFromBrooklyn He said he didn't want a GUI way of doing it. My guess is that the OP might want a command that he can put into a post-install script to automatically customize future MATE installations.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 That's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some trail and error, countless directory, file diff-ing, and also digging a little bit into Mate-Panel source code ([panel.c](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-panel/blob/master/mate-panel/panel.c)), confirmed following:

**Step to remove panel manually**

(1) All **objects** of target panel have to be removed

- Delete object's folder in `~/mateconf/app/panel/objects/`
- Delete object's reference from `/apps/panel/general/object_id_list` in `~/mateconf/app/general/%mateconf.xml`

(2) All **applets** of target panel have to be removed

- Delete applet's folder in `~/mateconf/app/panel/applets/`
- Delete applet's reference from `/apps/panel/general/applet_id_list` in `~/mateconf/app/general/%mateconf.xml`

(3) Remove Panel

- Delete panel's folder in `~/mateconf/app/panel/toplevels/`
- Delete panel's reference from `/apps/panel/general/toplevel_id_list` in `~/mateconf/app/general/%mateconf.xml`

Long story short, following is the result

**DEL_PANEL** is panel to be deleted. Currently is set to top panel.

```
#!/bin/bash

PANEL_PATH="${HOME}/.mateconf/apps/panel"
DEL_PANEL='top_panel_screen0'

    echo 'DEBUG: Panel Path' ${PANEL_PATH}
    echo 'DEBUG: Panel to be deleted' ${DEL_PANEL}

# -- Get old toplevel id list

TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_OLD=`mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/toplevel_id_list | cut -d\[ -f2 | cut -d\] -f1 | sed 's/,/ /g'`

    echo 'DEBUG: Old toplevel_id_list' ${TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_OLD}

# -- Generate new toplevel id list

TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_NEW=''
for i in ${TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_OLD}
do
    if [[ "$DEL_PANEL" != *"${i}"* ]]
    then
        echo -e "DEBUG: \tKeep ${i}"
        TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_NEW="${TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_NEW} ${i}"
    else
        echo -e "DEBUG: \tDel  ${i}"
        # -- Delete panel folder
        rm -rf ${PANEL_PATH}/toplevels/${i}
    fi
done
TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_NEW="[`echo ${TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_NEW} | sed 's/ /,/g'`]"

# -- Apply new toplevel id list
mateconftool-2 -s /apps/panel/general/toplevel_id_list -t list --list-type=string "${TOPLEVEL_ID_LIST_NEW}"

    echo 'DEBUG: New toplevel_id_list' `mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/toplevel_id_list`


# - APPLETS
# -- Identify applet to be deleted

cd ${PANEL_PATH}/applets
DEL_APPLET=`grep -r ${DEL_PANEL} *|cut -d\/ -f1`

    echo 'DEBUG: DEL_APPLET' ; for i in ${DEL_APPLET} ; do echo -e "DEBUG: \t${i}" ; done

# -- Get old applet id list

APPLET_ID_LIST_OLD=`mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/applet_id_list | cut -d\[ -f2 | cut -d\] -f1 | sed 's/,/ /g'`

    echo 'DEBUG: Old applet_id_list' ${APPLET_ID_LIST_OLD}

# -- Generate new applet id list

APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW=''
for i in ${APPLET_ID_LIST_OLD}
do
    if [[ "$DEL_APPLET" != *"${i}"* ]]
    then
        echo -e "DEBUG: \tKeep ${i}"
        APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW="${APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW} ${i}"
    else
        echo -e "DEBUG: \tDel  ${i}"
        # -- Delete applet folder
        rm -rf ${PANEL_PATH}/applets/${i}
    fi
done
APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW="[`echo ${APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW} | sed 's/ /,/g'`]"

# -- Apply new applet id list
mateconftool-2 -s /apps/panel/general/applet_id_list -t list --list-type=string "${APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW}"

    echo 'DEBUG: New applet_id_list' `mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/applet_id_list`


# - OBJECTS
# -- Identify object to be deleted

cd ${PANEL_PATH}/objects
DEL_OBJECT=`grep -r ${DEL_PANEL} *|cut -d\/ -f1`

    echo 'DEBUG: DEL_OBJECT' ; for i in ${DEL_OBJECT} ; do echo -e "DEBUG: \t${i}" ; done

# -- Get old object id list

OBJECT_ID_LIST_OLD=`mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/object_id_list | cut -d\[ -f2 | cut -d\] -f1 | sed 's/,/ /g'`

    echo 'DEBUG: Old object_id_list' ${OBJECT_ID_LIST_OLD}

# -- Generate new object id list

OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW=''
for i in ${OBJECT_ID_LIST_OLD}
do
    if [[ "$DEL_OBJECT" != *"${i}"* ]]
    then
        echo -e "DEBUG:\tKeep ${i}"
        OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW="${OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW} ${i}"
    else
        echo -e "DEBUG:\tDel  ${i}"
        # -- Delete object folder
        rm -rf ${PANEL_PATH}/objects/${i}
    fi
done
OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW="[`echo ${OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW} | sed 's/ /,/g'`]"

# -- Apply new object id list
mateconftool-2 -s /apps/panel/general/object_id_list -t list --list-type=string "${OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW}"

    echo 'DEBUG: New applet_id_list' `mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/object_id_list`
```

**Testing Environment**

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Mate Desktop: 1.4.x, Mate Official Repo for Ubuntu from [here](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download).

Comment: Absolutely wonderful!, I can't Thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the dconf key `org.mate.session.required-component.panel` to the empty string also works. You can probably do this using a dconf command like:

```
dconf write /org/mate/session/required-components/panel "''"
```

Edit: Oh, I did not see the part **one** of the **two**. Sorry. I hope it might help other people though.